# Return all items that are only used once in table

Tags: sql, t-sql

*List the names of all ingredients that are used in only one recipe (1 column, 46 rows)*

Logically the way I understand this query is that I need count the `IngredientID`'s in the `Recipe_Ingredients` column to find the instances where an `IngredientID` appears only once. But my query isn't returning any results.

I've tried substituting `count(Ingredients.IngredientID)` with `count(*)` and `sum()`. But both returned no results as well.

```
select Ingredients.IngredientName
from Ingredients
join Recipe_Ingredients on Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
group by Ingredients.IngredientName
having count(Ingredients.IngredientID) = 1;
```

[DB Structure SQL File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZUft0LV8QIEZu8D6wtaL0A5WQqb0j8S/view?usp=sharing)

[DB Data SQL File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bEW8ZjMN_5seFYI1bUCQ9apidU0Ztsa9/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not joining on the correct column; it should be

```
Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
```

Making this change gives the correct result of 46 rows: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfae015659be877efc1e59893ff7af65)

Note that preparing a dbfiddle as I did makes it a lot easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error. Also thanks for showing me the DBFiddle. I'll definitely use that for when I submit questions.

Comment: @Tomarik no worries. There are other dbfiddle sites as well, [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) offer some different engines as well as text to DDL capability which is really useful

Comment: Could you help me with one more query I've been struggling with? It keeps returning the incorrect number of rows.

Comment: @Tomarik happy to take a look - just ask another question.

Comment: I'm timed out for 90 minutes. I'm trying to setup DBFiddle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=801f38b91c132548bb48db89f46d9a7b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207078/discussion-between-tomarik-and-nick).

Answer (score 2):

Get the ingredients that are in the table of Recipe_Ingredients  only once.

```
select * from Ingredients a where IngredientID in
(
select IngredientID
from Recipe_Ingredients 
group by IngredientID
having count(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Ingredients.IngredientName
from Ingredients
join Recipe_Ingredients on Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
group by Ingredients.IngredientName
having count(Ingredients.IngredientID) = 1;
```